# Quotient in Windows phone 7 + silverlight + C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, math

Is there any inbuilt function to get quotient of a division. `Math.DivRem` is not appplicable it seems.

Comment: Why is Math.DivRem not applicable, what is your numerical type, what exactly do you want? Quotient is always just `a/b`.

Comment: You should explain what you really want, because the word *quotient* just means the result of a division. If you want the result of a division, just use the `/` operator.

Comment: using `DivRem` gives error "System.Math does not contain definition of DivRem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division of integer operands will yield the integer quotient. If your inputs are floating point types, just first convert them to integer types:

```
double num1 = 27;
int num2 = 7;
double dblResult = num1 / num2; // will yield floating point result 3.857...
int intResult    =(int)num1 / num2; // will yield integer quotient 3
```

Comment: The second division will not compile.